# Keras: Different generators for different grid patches of an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a huge dataset of images that I want to split into a grid of patches, e.g.a grid of 10 times 10 patches. For each of these different patches I want to train an autoencoder, so in the case of a 10x10-grid I would have 100 autoencoders.

My solution so far is to create a new ImageDataGenerator for each of the patches. But I believe this is too inefficient, since then all images need to be loaded completely 100 times (for each autoencoder once), although only one patch is needed. In theory one time would be sufficient. Is there a better way I don't see? Thanks in advance!

```
def crop_to_patch_function(patch_x: int, patch_y: int, grid_size: int):
    def crop_to_patch(img):
        x, y = patch_x*grid_size, patch_y*grid_size
        return img[y:(y+grid_size), x:(x+grid_size), :]
    return crop_to_patch


def patch_generator(patch_x, patch_y, grid_size):
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
    train_batches_tmp = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory=train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='input',
    )
    while True:
        batch_x, batch_y = next(train_batches_tmp)
        batch_patches = np.zeros((batch_x.shape[0], grid_size, grid_size, 3))
        for i in range(batch_x.shape[0]):
            batch_patches[i] = crop_to_patch_function(patch_x, patch_y, grid_size)(batch_x[i])
        yield (batch_patches, batch_patches)


# batches of patch at pos (2, 4)
patch_x, patch_y = 2, 4
train_patch_batches = patch_generator(patch_x, patch_y, grid_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing your images by creating the patches beforehand wouldn't work? Save them to different directories and assign each ImageDataGenerator to one of the 100 directories, loading data for each model.

Something like:

```
def images_to_patches(images_list):
    for idx,image in enumerator(images_list):
        for patch_x in range(10):
            for patch_y in range(10):
                //returns the patch image
                patch_img = crop_patch(image, patch_x, patch_y, grid_size)
                img_dir = str(patch_x)+str(patch_y)
                patch_img.save(os.path.join(img_dir,idx))
```